# Dynamic realloc inside a function - C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc, pass-by-value

I seem to have a problem with reallocating memory of arrays inside a function. Whenever the code gets to realloc, it is shut down due to Segmentation fault.

I call malloc in main:

```
char* coded_message = (char*) malloc(BASE_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
read_input(&coded_message, &original_message, &char_counter);
```

Than pass it to a function, which is reading input an if needed be reallocates the memory. So I the function goes like this:

```
int read_input(char** coded_message){
    ...
    *coded_message = (char*) realloc(*coded_message, (counter + REALLOC_LENGTH) * sizeof(char));
    ...
}
```

Comment: you just edited the code to be substantially different, please do not do that. If you have a new question then post a new question, and include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That answer does not help me at all

Comment: The duplicate answered the code you originally posted. Now you edit the question to be completely different.

Answer (score 1):

C uses pass-by value. The function arguments are passed by value to the called function, thus any chnages made to the argument will not *reflect back* to the caller.

In this case, from the function `read_input()`, the assignment (return value of `realloc()`) to the `original_message` will not reflect back to the caller, `main()`.

In other words, you can change the content pointed to by `read_input`, can be changed, but the `read_input` itself cannot be changed. If you want to change the pointer itself, you need to pass a pointer to the pointer.

Comment: You need to use char** blah, and modify/use *blah

Comment: sorry - don't really know how to format comments properly.So I the function uses `int read_input(char** coded_message){*coded_message = (char*) realloc(*coded_message, (counter + REALLOC_LENGTH) * sizeof(char));}`while in the main I first call malloc like this `char* coded_message = (char*) malloc(BASE_LENGTH * sizeof(char));` So are you saying in the main it should be a pointer to a pointer ** and I should use pointer * in function arguments?

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to `read_input` itself, like `&read_input`.